# Node.js from localhost

Tags: node.js

I'm experimenting with nodejs on my localhost now.

I do have a simple server host but I don't have SSH access etc.
How can I share my work with people in this situation?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

you could do a couple of things:

- open the port: meaning not running node.js as localhost and make sure it can be connected via the internet. You can use [grc's shield up to test if the port is reachable](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2).
- tunnel it via [tunnelr](http://tunnlr.com/) for example.
- deploy your script to [nodester](http://nodester.com/).
- share your screen via [teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com).

Answer (score 0):

A little more complicated, but you could buy a domain (through Google this would be about $10 US for a .com address, or as little as $2 US for a .info through GoDaddy.com) and then use a service like freedns.afraid.org to port all domain traffic to your domain.  This way you can run your scripts on whatever port you like on localhost.

Here's a howto to make that work:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1020886

This way you can run everything off of your local computer and not have to worry about the ssh access restrictions.